# How do I clone and create a build pipeline from YML pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, azure-pipelines

I can clone and create a new pipeline in a classic pipeline using `GetDefinitionAsync()` & `CreateDefinitionAsync()` methods provided in .Net SDK with the required parameter.
However, When I am trying to do the same with the YML pipeline, it is creating a pipeline, but the yml file's content where different tasks and steps should mention but remains blank.

I tried the same methods which are used for classic pipelines and expected a build pipeline for the YML pipeline.